# Extend MySQL datasource in CakePHP 2

Tags: cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to port a CakePHP 1.3 plugin to CakePHP 2.

What is causing me some trouble is when extending MySQL.

The file is located at /app/Plugin/PluginName/Model/Datasource and is PluginSource.php

Old line to extend mysql was:

```
class PluginSource extends DboMysqli { ...
```

Which I replaced, because DboMysqli is no longer available, with:

```
class PluginSource extends Mysql { ...
```

but it keeps giving me the following error:

```
Error: Class 'Mysql' not found
```

Please, can anyone help me finding this class to extend it? I know in which folder is, but can't extend it from there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Inform Cake about the Mysql.php location by adding the following to the top of the file:

```
App::uses('Mysql', 'Model/Datasource/Database');
```